A question on the optimisation problem and FWL theorem
Let's say we have the following model:
$$(\beta^{\star},f^{\star}) := \arg\min_{\beta,f \in \mathcal{F}} \mathbb{E}[\left(Z_i - f(X_i, E_i) -  \beta^\top \boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}\right)^2|S_i^{tr} = 1],$$
where $S_i^{tr}$ is an indicator function for treated units and $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all possible functions of $(X_i,E_i)$. Specifically, I'm considering the case in the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2403.19563. The authors say that by the Frisch-Waugh-Lovell (FWL) theorem, we can write
$$\beta^{\star} = \left(\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{V}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i]|S_i^{tr} = 1]\right)^{-1}\mathbb{E}[\left(\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i} - \mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i]\right)Z_i|S_i^{tr} = 1]$$ but I do not understand why and how this can solve the problem. My guess is that it serves to isolate the effect of a set of variables on both sides of a regression equation. Yet, I want some mathematical insights to this way of solving this problem. Any help or explanation is appreciated.

Are you asking how the authors have used the FWL theorem to get that expression for $\beta^$? Or are you asking why that expression for $\beta^$ is useful?

@JosephBasford Well, the answer to both would be helpful.

I haven't read the paper you reference, but I think I can give the general idea of how the methodology works.
Derivation of $\boldsymbol{\beta}^*$
To derive the $\beta^*$ expression, we take the common FWL approach of "washing" out one dimension of the noise in the dependent variable. In this case, by washing out the noise in $Z_i$ explainable by $(X_i,E_i)$, we get the component of $Z_i$ which is orthogonal to $f(X_i,E_i)$.
First, the model under consideration is something like $$Z_i=f(X_i,E_i)+\beta^T\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}+\varepsilon_i \qquad \text{Given } S_i^{tr}=1$$ along with the strict exogeneity assumption that $\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_i|X_i,E_i,\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i},S_i^{tr}=1]$=0, (cf. expression (5) in the paper).
Consider the conditional expectation when we are given $(X_i,E_i)$, $$\mathbb{E}[Z_i|X_i,E_i]=f(X_i,E_i)+\beta^T\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i]+\mathbb{E}[\varepsilon_i|X_i,E_i]=f(X_i,E_i)+\beta^T\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i]$$
where the final equality follows by the law of iterated expectation and the strict exogeneity assumption. One may have to additionally condition on $S_i^{tr}=1$ in the above, but this does not affect the conclusion since $\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}$ is a function of $(X_i,E_i)$ only (see below).
Whence, we obtain that $$\begin{align} (\beta^*,f)&=\arg\min_{\beta,f\in \mathcal{F}}\mathbb{E}[(Z_i-\mathbb{E}[Z_i|X_i,E_i]+\mathbb{E}[Z_i|X_i,E_i]-f(X_i,E_i)-\beta^T\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i})^2|S_i^{tr}=1] \\
\beta^*&=\arg\min_{\beta}\mathbb{E}[(Z_i-\mathbb{E}[Z_i|X_i,E_i]-\beta^T(\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}-\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i]))^2|S_i^{tr}=1] \end{align}$$
Applying the standard regression result, we find $$\beta^*=(\mathbb{E}[(\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}-\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i])(\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}-\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i])^T|S_i^{tr}=1])^{-1}\mathbb{E}[(\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}-\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i])(Z_i-\mathbb{E}[Z_i|X_i,E_i])|S_i^{tr}=1]$$
This is not quite the stated result yet. First, we simplify the denominator.
By law of iterated expectation, we can turn our expression into $$\beta^*=(\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}-\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i])(\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}-\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i])^T|S_i^{tr}=1,X_i,E_i]|S_i^{tr}=1])^{-1}\mathbb{E}[(\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}-\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i])(Z_i-\mathbb{E}[Z_i|X_i,E_i])|S_i^{tr}=1]$$
On page 17 of the paper, it is stated that the policy paths are deterministic functions of $(X_i,E_i)$ and that therefore $\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}$ are functions of only $(X_i,E_i)$. I believe this means we can remove the $S_i^{tr}$ conditioning from the inner expectation. This results in, $$\beta^*=(\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{V}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i]|S_i^{tr}=1])^{-1}\mathbb{E}[(\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}-\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i])(Z_i-\mathbb{E}[Z_i|X_i,E_i])|S_i^{tr}=1]$$
Next, we simplify the numerator. To do this, simply note that by law of iterated expectation, the numerator is the covariance of $\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}$ and $Z_i$ given $(X_i,E_i)$. As this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513153/show-that-the-covariance-is-also-mathrmcovx-y-ex-exy-exy-ey points out, we can simplify this covariance to remove the $\mathbb{E}[Z_i|X_i,E_i]$ term. Therefore, $$\beta^*=(\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{V}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i]|S_i^{tr}=1])^{-1}\mathbb{E}[(\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}-\mathbb{E}[\boldsymbol{\tau}_{i,E_i}|X_i,E_i])Z_i|S_i^{tr}=1]$$
as desired.

Utility of This Methodology
This sort of methodology of washing out the noise associated with more complicated components is extremely useful, especially in partially linear models such as this one. Finding the optimal $f$ is much more complicated than finding the optimal $\beta$, since it is a functional problem rather than a standard multivariate optimisation problem. By netting out the noise associated with $(X_i,E_i)$, we have derived a succinct closed-form expression for $\beta^*$ which does not include $f$. Therefore, we can analyse $\beta^*$ without ever having to derive a closed-form solution for optimal $f$, which, as stated, is intractable.
This approach is precisely what the Robinson (1988, referenced in the paper) estimator does, which was likely part of the inspiration for this methodology. The asymptotics of this sort of estimator for $\beta$ are often exceptionally good, having a $\sqrt{n}$ rate convergence no matter the dimension of $X_i$. In the paper, there are more complications compared with the Robinson estimator, but the approach is similar.
In the paper, they go on to analyse the components of this $\beta^*$ expression, which was only tractable due to the application of the FWL theorem. Without applying this methodology, they would have no closed form expression for $\beta^*$.

Thanks a lot for your explanation. That cleared up a lot for me!
